# C Program - How to assign values of a char* array to a 2d char* array?

Tags: c, pointers

Im trying to initialize a 2d array representing a deck of cards from 2 char pointer arrays called faces and suit representing the faces and suits of cards. I'm getting various errors shown below and cannot work out how to properly add values to my deck as well display my deck. Could anyone point out to me what needs to change in order for my code to work? Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "functions.h"

char **deck[4][13];

char *suit[] = {
    "Hearts",
    "Diamonds",
    "Clubs",
    "Spades"};
char *faces[] = {
    "Ace",
    "Two",
    "Three",
    "Four",
    "Five",
    "Six",
    "Seven",
    "Eight",
    "Nine",
    "Ten",
    "Jack",
    "Queen",
    "King",
};

char** initializeDeck(char** arr)
{
    char addToString[] = " of ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] =  *faces[j], addToString, *suit[i]
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

void displayDeck(char** arr){
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
        {
            printf("[%s] ", **arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

errors:

```
functions.c:35:37: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
            arr[i][j] =  *faces[j], addToString, *suit[i];
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~
functions.c:35:50: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
            arr[i][j] =  *faces[j], addToString, *suit[i];
                                                 ^~~~~~~~
functions.c:46:30: error: indirection requires pointer operand ('int' invalid)
            printf("[%s] ", **arr[i][j]);
```

Comment: explain what in your opinion this statement is doing `arr[i][j] =  *faces[j], addToString, *suit[i]` ? Hint - it is not connecting strings together.

Comment: @0___________ Honestly thats what I thought it would do, I saw somewhere that was a way to concatenate the strings

Comment: Then you need to go back to your textbook. BTW the whole code makes not too much sense. You need to rethink rewrite it completely.  `**arr[i][j]` - you need to reread "pointers and arrays" chapter in your book. Before that it will be very hard to help you

Comment: @0___________ I mean I understand that my deck is holding the pointers to pointers to strings, I just havent been able to find the syntax to initialize it it with the other pointers from my other arrays

Comment: No - your `arr` pointer to pointer to char.  string in c is an array of chars.  So you need to have pointer to pointer to pointer to char. You need to allocate space for the strings. You cant index it this way

Answer (score 0):

1. `arr[i][j] =  *faces[j], addToString, *suit[i]` is not contcatenating the strings together.

Here you have some code but I do not think that your teacher will belive that is your code

```
char *myconcat(const char *s1, const char *s2, const char *s3)
{
    size_t len = strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + strlen(s3);
    char *newstr = malloc(len + 1);
    
    if(newstr)
    {
        strcpy(newstr, s1);
        strcat(newstr, s2);
        strcat(newstr, s3);
    }
    return newstr;
}


char *(*initializeDeck(void))[13]
{
    char *(*cards)[13] = malloc(4 *sizeof(*cards));
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
        {
            cards[i][j] =  myconcat(faces[j], " of ", suit[i]);
        }
    }
    return cards;
}

void displayDeck(char *(*cards)[13]){
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++)
        {
            printf("[%s] ", cards[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks for doing that, I'll reference your code and try to learn a little more about pointers like you suggested

Comment: This is abit moreadvanced as I use pointers to arrays of pointers\

Comment: yeah I can definitely tell, I couldn't write that on my own lol,  are those pointer functions? and is the size necessary in the function header when returning an array? Ive never seen that before

Comment: no it is not function pointer. It is function returning pointer to array of 13 char pointers

Comment: the code would be simplified if `typedef char *faces_t[13];`  was added and used

Comment: This typedef will not help at all. How char of 13 chars would help?

Comment: Hey just a quick question about this, If initialize deck is returning an array of 13 char pointers, doesn't that mean its only a 1d array and should be holding only one suit at a time? How is it turning into a 2d array of pointers to arrays of 13 pointers? I tested your code and I know it works I'm just not fully understanding how that's working exactly. If you could help me out with that id really appreciate it if not thanks anyway!